# How to delete a row on the master tab (destination) and also delete the same row value on the tab it was queried from automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-cleaning, data-management, data-collection

This is a probably convoluted process in data collection. Any advice on how to best do this will be appreciated.

I am working on data collection and I am trying to clean it real time. The data is set up such hat each RA has their own tab on google sheet to put in observations. Then I have this master sheet that queries from all the RA tabs to create this master data. The master sheet can tell me which are duplicates and which of those duplicates have a better quality of information.

Doing a master data using query does not allow me to edit on it, for some reason. So, I copy and paste as value to another tab. I use the master tab to analyze any duplicate information. Ideally, when I clean the master tab and delete the lesser quality duplicate, it also deletes from the RA tab it originated from. How do I do this? Is this the best way of doing this? In a similar fashion, if I would like to edit in the master sheet and also have that row to be edited in the original tab.

I created a trial sheet to practice with.

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12XhUzH_v565C8fll_JwjloU0E12XmVarXesrUY83D-4/edit?usp=sharing](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I have been doing this manually and wondering if there is a better way. I am open to using google apps script but I am still a new at that. I am thinking of using onEdit function but I do not know how to test my code or how to know what is in e.

Comment: QUERY takes a data range as reference, and process according to what you write inside it,  if you want to change the data inside a QUERY, you should instead change the referenced data pages.

Comment: Is it needed to keep / alter the data in the RA sheet? Otherwise just make the values in master `hardcoded` and just work from there.

Answer (score 0):

> The data is set up such hat each RA has their own tab on google sheet to put in observations.

One easy solution would be to keep *all* the data in the master tab, have everyone edit that tab only, and use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to give every user their own private view so that everyone only sees "their" rows. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.